# When to use monads from scalaz?

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz

I'd like to create a simple wrapper for computations. The built-in scala monads (`TraversableLike`) seems sufficient for me. And they have already syntax sugar. From some point of view scala collection traits are accidental monads. And there intended monads provided by the scalaz library.

What uses cases benefit from complex type classed monads of scalaz? What functionality is unfeasible for built-in monads and indicate need for scalaz?

---

Some clarification.

This question is not a holy war inheritance vs type classes. My question is about infrastructure that provides scalaz. Not any library with type classes approach, but this mentioned library. It slightly complicates things. But also it have bunch of utility classes that have no matches in scala collection library. Because it is a collection library, not a monadic. So the question is about the additional functionality provided by scalaz. In which cases does it matter?

Comment: Writing pure I/O code (scalaz.effect.IO, scalaz.concurrent.Task) is painful without monads.

Comment: `So the question is about the additional functionality provided by scalaz. In which cases does it matter?` -- It matters when people calling your classes want to use them in generic code which uses scalaz typeclasses.

Answer (score 4):

First for a point about terminology: it's sometimes useful shorthand to say things like "`Option` is a monad", but "`Option` has a monad instance" or "`Option` is monadic" is clearer. It's potentially a little confusing to say that Scalaz provides a bunch of monads—what it provides is a `Monad` type class and instances of that type class for a number of types, including some of its own (e.g. `\/`, `Task`, etc.) and some from the standard library (`List`, `Option`, etc.).

So I'm going to answer a question which is similar to your question: what's the value of an explicit `Monad` type class over the monadic syntactic sugar provided by the standard library?

One place where having an explicit `Monad` representation is useful is when you want to define your own generic combinators or operations. Suppose I want to write a method `addM` that takes two monadic `M[Int]` values and adds them in the monad. It's easy to write for `Option`:

```
def addM(oa: Option[Int], ob: Option[Int]): Option[Int] = for {
  a <- oa
  b <- ob
} yield a + b
```

Or for lists:

```
def addM(oa: List[Int], ob: List[Int]): List[Int] = for {
  a <- oa
  b <- ob
} yield a + b
```

These two implementations obviously have a lot in common, and it'd be nice to be able to write a single generic implementation that would work in both cases—and for any other monadic type as well. This is really hard if we only have the standard library's hand-wavy monadic syntax, and really easy if we have a `Monad` type class.

Comment: TraversableLike is in fact a monad class. It have all monad methods.  It just has misleading name and bunch of redundant methods

Comment: `TraversableLike` isn't a type class, though—it's a base class that provides some monad-y methods.

Comment: Type Classes is not the single method for polymorphic dispatching available in scala. Should I write example of generic definition for addM in terms of TraversableLike?

Comment: Such an implementation would require its generic type to implement `TraversableLike`. That's fine, but in some cases ad-hoc polymorphism is better. Scalaz is designed to support those cases.

Comment: I agree. I would however argue that the bigger reason is semantics and expressing monadic behaviour within a type chain.

Comment: @TravisBrown Ad-hoc is usefull when you adopt already existed classes into monadic paradigm. But I'm just started to design my library and monadic usage is one of key requirements. So I intend to write monad either as traversablelike descendant or providing implicit evidence for scalaz monad. The latter is more troublesome, so I'm asking what benefits it has comparing to simple aproach

Comment: That sounds more like a general question about the benefits of type classes over inheritance.

Comment: This question is too abstract to have exact answer. My question is more about infrastructure that provides scalaz. Not any library with type classes approach, but this mentioned library. It slightly complicates things. But also it have bunch of utility classes that  have no matches in scala collection library. Because it is a collection library, not a monadic. So the question is about the additional functionality provided by scalaz. In which cases does it matter?

Comment: Some monadic types just can't be made to extend `TraversableLike`, either for practical reasons (you don't control them) or semantic reasons (`IO` isn't traversable).

Comment: I'm writing one, so I could control it. And it perfectly fit to be TraversableLike, not less than Option.